# browser-solidity debug alternative for more automate process (rather than manually type in the function input everytime)

Tags: truffle, remix, contract-debugging

As specified in the title
I use truffle to test now, but often times it just returns the error msg "invalid opcode" instead of clearly stating what happened. 
Any other testing/debugging tips will also be much appreciated >< 
Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pyethereum tester: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/wiki/Using-pyethereum.tester

This is much faster than using a truffle workflow with testrpc, and much more flexible: You can test the return values of functions, store the blockchain state to do repeated tests on it, change the block timestamp etc.